# Testing for difference of distances from a mean to a reference (but unknown) mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mean

Given samples $(x_i)$, $(y_i)$ and $(z_i)$ where:
$$X_i \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma^2),$$
$$Y_i \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma^2),$$
$$Z_i \sim N(\mu_{ref},\sigma^2),$$

with $\mu_X, \mu_Y, \mu_{ref}$ and $ \sigma$ unknown and everything independent.

Is there a standard test for $H_{0}: |\mu_X-\mu_{ref}| \ne |\mu_Y-\mu_{ref}|$ ?

Moreover, is there a vectorial version i.e. where :
$H_{0}:||\pmb{\mu_X}-\pmb{\mu_{ref}}|| \ne ||\pmb{\mu_Y}-\pmb{\mu_{ref}}||$ with $\pmb{\mu_X}$, $\pmb{\mu_Y}$ and $\pmb{\mu_X}$ $\in R^n$.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "vectorial version"?  After all, the standard tests for this least-squares regression model usually are described in terms of "contrast" vectors.

Comment: @whuber I updated my answer according to your question